# Why does my MongoDB driver timeout compared to when I run the same query in Studio3T

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have some simple code as follows (I have removed some of the definitions for brevity):

```
  var collection = _Mongo.GetCollection<Change>("changes");

  var items = collection.AsQueryable<Change>();
  items = items.Where(f => f.OrgId == search.OrgId);
  items = items.OrderByDescending(f => f.DateChange);
  items = items.Skip(search.Offset).Take(search.Count);

  Logger.LogInformation(items.GetExecutionModel().ToString());
  result.Changes = await items.ToListAsync();
```

The log output shows the following:

```
{aggregate([{ "$match" : { "OrgId" : "3810" } }, { "$sort" : { "DateChange" : -1 } }, { "$skip" : 0 }, { "$limit" : 50 }])}
    OutputSerializer: {MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer<TrackerCommon.Models.Change>}
    OutputType: {Name = "Change" FullName = "TrackerCommon.Models.Change"}
    Stages: Count = 4
```

When I put the mongo aggregate code into Studio3T it takes 1.019 seconds to bring back results. However, for this database (the collection currently has 2,415,782 records), when  I use the code, it times out. It works on a smaller database fine so I believe the connection code is OK. (What is more it has no problem adding items to the collection).

I have the following indexes set up:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "$**" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "$**_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "DateChange" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "DateChange_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "Area" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "Area_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "Area" : 1.0,
            "Field" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "Area_1_Field_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "Action" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "Action_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "OrgId" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "OrgId_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1.0,
        "key" : {
            "ChangedBy" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "ChangedBy_1",
        "ns" : "Audit.changes"
    }
]
```

I am uncertain if I have the indexes set up for optimal performance but at the same time it does work quickly in Studio3T.

Comment: You'll want a compound index on `{ OrgId: 1, DateChange: -1 }`. Once you have that you can also drop the current single field index in `{ OrgId: 1 }` as it will be redundant and superceded by the compound index

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried the query without the orgId parameter and it did not make any difference. (rather than adjusting the index for now)

Comment: Meaning the aggregation pipeline starting from the $sort (and with a $skip value of 0) also timed out? How long is a timeout? Something is definitely not right then. Check `mongod` logs for the associated connection and see what it has to say. Either the index you want isn't there or it's hitting the wrong namespace or you're being throttled or... (You will want that other index for this query long term, but definitely sounds like there is some other problem as well)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been working on this and have determined that, if I set up the MongoClient and IMongoDatabase object in the same method I don't get the same delay (although I do if I am doing a Count across the result set but otherwise to return a limited number of records it is much quicker). The question is why?!

Comment: Be careful to avoid making inappropriate comparisons, eg between 'apples and oranges'. Counting forces all documents to be processed whereas other queries can process and return smaller amounts contained in just the first (of potentially many) batch. How long does it take to get to the last result? Also comparing those operations is seemingly different than comparing 'setup time' introduced by having MongoClient and IMongoDatabase in different locations. Keep all but one thing the same when comparing, isolating the bottlenecks one at a time, and then addressing the biggest ones first